# Spring data querying many-to-one column

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Hello I've been struggling in my error, since I'm new to Spring data, I have a models called user and role and i want to query a user with role but the role can't query from jpa here is my sample code

User Module:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private String username;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String middleName;

@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
private Role role;

private Boolean isDisable;
//getter and setters here
}
```

Role Module:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String roleName;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<String> privileges;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="role")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<User> users;
//getter and setter
}
```

Role Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Long>{
User findByUsername(String username);
List<User> findAll();
}
```

User Service Implementation:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

@Autowired
private final UserRepository userRepository;

public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Override
public User findByUsername(String username) {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
}

@Override
public List<User> findAll() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public User findById(Long id) {
    return userRepository.findById(id).get();
}

@Override
public User save(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
}
```

User Service:

```
@Repository
public interface UserService {

User findByUsername(String string);
List<User> findAll();
User findById(Long id);
User save(User user);
}
```

Response:

```
{
"id": 4,
"username": "user",
"password": "$2a$10$ZQMkXzXAXyFvvrZ38UnWkuLpe34pM9c2Qnir/4dtZFyxsANYRkMYy",
"firstName": "user-firstname",
"lastName": "user-lastname",
"middleName": "user-middlename",
"disable": false
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Could you add the logs?

Comment: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
it means there is no problem that raised by the spring

Comment: Add  @JoinColumn for Role object in User class.

Comment: Hmm, could you check if: 1. `User` entity has a `getRole()` ? 2. The relationship between `User` and `Role` exist on DB (there is an entry on the join table) 3. Or perhaps the usage of `@JsonBackReference` and `@JsonManagedReference` is wrong?

Comment: 1. my User entity has a getRole()

Comment: What about 2. The relationship between User and Role in DB ?

Comment: my user db has a foreign key of role id

Comment: 3. i switched the JsonBackReference to JsonManagedReference and vice versa then the role from the user appears but i cant create a new

Comment: You cant create a new user? May you need cascade @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)?